# FFMpeg combine two separate commands

Tags: ffmpeg

I am running 2 seperate ffmpeg commands..

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -vf scale=1024:768 -crf 0 output_video.mp4

ffmpeg -i output_video.mp4 -s 640x360 -c:v libx264 -preset slow -b:v 650k -r 24 -x264opts keyint=48:min-keyint=48:no-scenecut -profile:v main -preset fast -movflags +faststart -c:a libfdk_aac -b:a 128k -ac 2 out-low.mp4
```

Is there a way I can do both of these commands in once go?  Trying to avoid 2 encoding sessions reducing the quality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Label filter outputs and refer to them in the `-map` option:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v]scale=1024:768[v768];[0:v]scale=640:360[v360]"
  -map "[v768]" -map 0:a -c:v libx264 -c:a copy -crf 0 output_video.mp4
  -map "[v360]" -map 0:a -c:v libx264 -preset slow -b:v 650k -r 24 -x264opts keyint=48:min-keyint=48:no-scenecut -profile:v main -preset fast -movflags +faststart -c:a libfdk_aac -b:a 128k -ac 2 out-low.mp4
```